# All possible ways to read a file from a remote server

Tags: php, javascript, file

i want to provide most possible flexibility for my script and so i need all possible ways in php and javascript to read the content(not sourcecode) of a php file from a remote server.
so far i found curl, fopen and include for php and none for javascript, but i dont even know if this is possible with javascript.
Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 3):

PHP:

```
  - fopen() + fread()
  - file_get_contents()
  - curl
  - executing shell commands
        `wget 'www.google.com' -O saved.htm`;
        $result = `cat saved.htm`;
```

JavaScript:

```
  // not for remote server
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', 'http://www.google.com', false);
  req.send(null);
  if (req.readyState==4) alert(req.responseText);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got the major options for PHP figured out.

As for javascript (assuming it's running in a web browser), the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) will complicate things.

Possible workaround for Javascript include:

- Using a [script-tag proxy](http://jaybyjayfresh.com/2007/09/17/using-script-tags-to-do-remote-http-calls-in-javascript/)
- Using a PHP proxy script on the domain that your page is loaded from.  Your javascript asks the PHP script to grab the remote content.  PHP script does that, and outputs the contents back to you javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a client side scripting language primarily, you can't just simply get an external resource with it without either

- server-side help ( xhr to
  server-side page to do curl/wget )
- the resource has to be on *your*
  domain and you can XMLHttpRequest it without server-side help.